# Class vs struct with enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, private-inheritance

I have a question. I was playing with `enable_shared_from_this` and noticed a strange thing. This example works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Test : enable_shared_from_this<Test>
{
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Test> ptr(new Test);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I change `struct` to `class` it stops compiling!

The error says:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:772:58: error:
‘std::enable_shared_from_this’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Test’
    __enable_shared_from_this_helper(_M_refcount, __p, __p);
```

Does anyone have a clue why it is so?

Comment: Default inheritance for `struct` is `public` whereas for `class`, it's `private` inheritance.

Comment: Right. The default inheritance is the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This might be a (minor) defect in the C++ Standard!

The difference between `struct` and `class` in the example is the default accessibility of base classes:

```
struct Test : enable_shared_from_this<Test>
```

derives *publicly* from `enable_shared_from_this`;

```
class Test : enable_shared_from_this<Test>
```

derives *privately* from `enable_shared_from_this`;

However, I cannot find any (normative) requirement in the Standard that requires an accessible `enable_shared_from_this` base class for *constructing* a `shared_ptr`.

[util.smartptr.enab]/6 about `enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this()` requires:

> `enable_shared_from_this<T>` shall be an accessible base class of `T`.

But I do not see where the Standard mandates using that function or any other explicit requirement about the accessibility of the `enable_shared_from_this` base class.

The possible implementation given in [util.smartptr.enab]/10-11 does require an accessible base class; so I think the normative parts are intended to require accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Add `public` before `enable_shared_from_this`

```
class Test : public enable_shared_from_this<Test>
{



};
```